# Move or copy and truncate a file that is in use

Tags: windows, linux, ffmpeg, copy, truncate

I want to be able to (programmatically) move (or copy and truncate) a file that is constantly in use and being written to. This would cause the file being written to would never be too big.

Is this possible? Either Windows or Linux is fine.

To be specific what I'm trying to do is log video with FFMPEG and create hour long videos.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in both Windows and Linux, but it would take cooperation between the applications involved.  If the application that is writing the new data to the file is not aware of what the other application is doing, it probably would not work (well ... there is some possibility ... back to that in a moment).

In general, to get this to work, you would have to open the file shared.  For example, if using the Windows API CreateFile, both applications would likely need to specify `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.  This would allow both (multiple) applications to read and write the file "concurrently".

Beyond sharing the file, though, it would also be necessary to coordinate the operations between the applications. You would need to use some kind of locking mechanism (either by locking some part of the file or some shared mutex/semaphore). Note that if you use file locking, you could lock some known offset in the file to act as a "semaphore" (it can even be a byte value beyond the physical end of the file). If one application were appending to the file at the same exact time that the other application were truncating it, then it would lead to unpredictable results.

Back to the comment about both applications needing to be aware of each other ...  It is possible that if both applications opened the file exclusively and kept retrying the operations until they succeeded, then perform the operation, then close the file, it would essentially allow them to work without "knowledge" of each other.  However, that would probably not work very well and not be very efficient.

Having said all that, you might want to consider alternatives for efficiency reasons.  For example, if it were possible to have the writing application write to new files periodically, it might be more efficient than having to "move" the data constantly out of one file to another.  Also, if you needed to maintain some portion of the file (e.g., move out the first 100 MB to another file and then move the second 100 MB to the beginning) that could be a fairly expensive operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

logrotate would be a good option is linux, comes stock on just about any distro. I'm sure there's a similar windows service out there somewhere